# How to specify windows version for Boost conan package?

Tags: c++, boost, conan

I use Boost 1.84 package from [conan.io](https://conan.io/center/recipes/boost?version=). Since Boost 1.84 [default version of Windows API](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/boost/winapi/config.hpp) is set to Windows 10.

```
By default use Windows 10 API on compilers that support it and latest versions on the others
```

I need to specify other, in particular `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 0x0601`. As far as I understand it can be achieved by passing define like `BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0601` to conan recipe somehow. How can I do this?

Tried the following changes in `export/conanfile.py`, but no luck:

```
cxx_flags.append(f"-DBOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0601")
self.cpp_info.components["headers"].defines.append("BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0601")
```

Comment: This could be different things, from something specific to the recipe, to something in the Conan client. In general it would be better to report in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues. You'd need to report the Conan version. The ``export`` folder, if it is the cache folder cannot be modified in the cache. Defining ``cpp_info`` is information for the consumers, not for building the current recipe.

Comment: In general passing ``tools.build:defines`` configuration (in profiles or command line), allows to inject arbitrary custom preprocessor definitions, but as boost uses its very specific build system I am not 100% sure it will use those.